# How to send an email with eiffel kernel library

Tags: email, eiffel

How can a mail be sent in eiffel with kernel library? which class to use?

Comment: You should be more specific: Do you want to submit an existing message, or do you want to compose* and submit a message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library `net` of standard EiffelStudio distribution provides means for sending messages with SMTP. A simple example of using this functionality is located in `.../examples/net/transport/smtp`.